# jQuery in Sublime text? Code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, sublimetext3

I am wondering if you can help. I am previewing my code in a Firefox build system using Sublime text 3. The HTML and CSS are fine however my jQuery dosen't work despite being properly linked etc. Here is my code:

Comment: Is that jQuery in another file? If so, have you included the file?

Comment: Change `//ajax.googleapis.com` to `http://ajax.googleapis.com`

Comment: I'm getting a 404 not found when I try to use that URL with both HTTP and HTTPS.  Can you verify that you are linking to the correct URL?

Comment: I have linked the jQuery here in my HTML head like so: <script type= "text/javascript" src="jquery/mouseenter.js"></script> and I have even attempted this: /Users/Nick/Documents/Work/Website/Mouseenter.js...is there something I'm missing? Thanks for the response

Comment: The version in the `googleapis` URL should be [`1.11.1`](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js) rather than `1.11.10`. The jQuery team hasn't released a 10th revision of `1.11`.

Comment: `jquery/mouseenter.js`? What's that?

Comment: a) Did you try my suggestion above and b) what errors does the browser give you/

Comment: @MDiesel I am using a build system for firefox from ST3

Comment: @j08691 I did, thanks. It is exactly the same just slower to launch the preview in the browser?

Comment: @esqew jquery/mouseenter.js that is my folder/filename for the source of my jQuery script

Comment: @NickR93 can you change the url to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js (removing the 0 after the very last 1) and see if that works

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Just noticed that, fixed but still no joy

Comment: are we overthinking here.....he is using $('manifesto').hover() instead of $('#manifesto').hover()....could that be why it is not working....??

Comment: @Phani I have just amended that also (apologies for messy code guys) and still it doesn't work...

Comment: Could you post your console output?

Answer (score 0):

I just observed one thing, you are adding the class and removing it immediately on hover hence the div is unaffected

Try this code, if **you are** trying to add the class only on hover and remove it when not hovered

```
$('#manifesto').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('manifestotitle');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('manifestotitle');
});
```

For reference see the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3965auq/2/

Hope this helped

Comment: thats already been discussed in the comments section for the question.....the problem still persists is what has been said....

Comment: @aroop the link is broken?

Comment: I can't seem to get get any hover or mouseover function to work adequately with my code...example: html: 
  <div class="left"><a href="#"><b>Nick Reilly</b></a>
  <P><b><i>(Holding Page)</i></b></P></div>

Answer (score 0):

I see in your CSS that "manifestotitle" refers to an id (#manifestotitle) could you try converting it to a class?

EDIT: Ok, I think I got it. I downloaded your code and messed around a bit. This is what I changed to make it work:

1. Change your CDN for jquery to the official one:
2. "manifestotitle" should be a class as your javascript is using it as one. So you should make these changes. In your HTML:

   `<div class="manifestotitle">`

And in your CSS file:

```
    `.manifestotitle {`
```

3. Fix your selector in your js:

   `$('#manifesto').hover(function () {`

That got it working for me, hope it helps!

Comment: @user2968356 the console output is too long to post but this is the start:          startup, version: 3065 osx x64 channel: stable
executable: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text
working dir: /
packages path: /Users/Nick/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /Users/Nick/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local
hardware concurrency: 4
zip path: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages
zip path: /Users/Nick/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant changing #manifestotitle {...} to .manifestotitle {...} in your css file.

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+K in Firefox, or F12 in Chrome and have a look at the console tab

Comment: @user2968356 I'm getting   'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }    Mouseenter.js:6' when opening showing the console in chrome

Answer (score -1):

*Not an answer however need to show more code!*

It seems I can't get .hover() and .mouseover() functions to work at all with my code...here is a simple example (using a class rather than an ID also):

```
HTML:
    <div class="left"><a href="#"><b>Nick Reilly</b></a>
    <P><b><i>(Holding Page)</i></b></P></div>

CSS:
.left {
color: #000000;
left: 50px;
position: fixed;
top: 40px;
font-size: 18px;
z-index: 100;
line-height: 15px;
}

jQuery:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#left").mouseover(function(){
addClass('.red');
});
});
```

Surely this should simply change the text I have to red when the mouse is over it? When I preview it in both a Firefox and Chrome build nothing happens!

Thanks